# Metrics for unbalanced classes

Tags: unbalanced-classes, metric

I have been looking for good metrics on this data set I am working, however it is highly unbalanced. It has a total of 8 categorical classes, one of them is responsible for ~40% of data, another for 20% and every other has around the same quantity. I was able to create  a model reaching 94% accuracy and another reached 91% accuracy, however when I check the confusion matrix of the second it hits better in the classes with fewer examples.

I know for this case accuracy is not the best metric, however every post/paper I read (like [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) and [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/)) just evaluate two classes. My question is: what other metrics, beside accuracy, should I use? What score tells me what model is the best for this poroblem?

Regards!

Comment: Use proper scoring rules. [See my answer in the proposed duplicate.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, some metrics used in such situations:

- [F1-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score).
- [Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa).
- [Geometric Mean Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean)
- [Intersection Over Union (Jaccard)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)

All of which essentially weigh the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) elements in a different way.

---

#### Aggregation

Besides selecting which metric suits your task the best, you should also consider isn't what metric you should use but **how to aggregate the results from each class**.

If you want you objectively evaluate the performance of your model and have **each class matter the same** regardless of the number of samples in the test set you could just **macro-average** the results!

Macro-averaging simply averages the metric's scores for each classes. This doesn't take into account at all class imbalance, regardless of the metric you choose.

Example:
(I'm going to use accuracy to prove my point. Generally speaking is a bad metric for class imbalance and you should avoid it.):

Class 1: $135/150$ (correct/total) --> $90\%$ (accuracy for class 1)
Class 2: $15/30$ --> $50\%$
Class 3: $5/20$ --> $20\%$

**micro-averaged accuracy**: $\frac{135 + 15 + 5}{150 + 30 + 20} = \frac{155}{200} = 77.5\%$ which is a very high score, not indicative of the model's actual performance because of the high imbalance.
**macro-averaged accuracy**: $\frac{90 + 50 + 20}{3}\% = 53.3\%$

Macro-averaging does have its issues, mainly that each sample of an under-represented class essentially counts more to the score than each one from the majority class. So in the example above if we made $10$ more correct predictions for class 3 then it would boost the overall performance of the model from $53.3\%$ to $71.6\%$, which is a massive improvement, that might simple occure due to a high bias towards class 3.

So see if it's right for you and **use with caution**. All metrics are good as long as you are aware what they represent.

Answer (score 0):

You should definetly use the F1 score which takes into account the mistakes on positives and negatives for all classes.
I deliver you to this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/accuracy-precision-recall-or-f1-331fb37c5cb9

Comment: [The F1 score is still an improper scoring rule and best avoided.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352)